# silent print or click print button in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf.js

I use pdf.js on in pe:documentViewer. It shows my pdf. I click print,it print normally.Now I want to silent print a pdf not show a viewer. I think using js to click print button. How to do it?

Comment: Do you have any code example to help understand the problem?